# How to distinguish between design patterns and standard polymorphism

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

For example I have one interface and a bunch of classes as follows

```
public interface Drawable{
  void draw(); // draws something on screen for example.
}

abstract class Shape implements Drawable {...}
class Circle extends Shape{...} // assume that draw() is implemented in both classes.
class Square extends Shape{...} // ...
```

Now if I have a main class and perform the following:

```
class Main{

Shape s1 = new Circle();
s1.draw(); // assume that this will draw a circle.

s1 = new Square();
s1.draw(); //assume that this will draw a square.

}
```

I'm I using a design pattern here? or is this just standard polymorphism? If this is a design pattern then what is it called?

Comment: in my opinion, design patterns are good practices/ways to use OOP principles. It is using OOP principles to make a lot of sense depending on a certain requirement. just a cent.

Comment: This is just polymorphism. Design Patterns made to perticular reasons. like Singleton pattern. it will manage just Single Object for whole Application. is this your code some perticular reason. And pattern is not java. Pattern is Way to make your code maintain. means you can use any language for its implementation.

Comment: Don't worry, it's all made up words, badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In my opinion, a design pattern is a tried-and-tested **manner** of writing code to solve a problem. The way in which you employ a given design pattern could significantly differ depending on the programming language you use.
- Design patterns are rarely supported at the language level (although newer languages like Groovy do implement particular design patterns at the language-level; for example, the "Method Object" pattern is provided in Groovy using a language level feature called "Closures").
- The code you've given is an example of Polymorphism, which is one of the fundamental concepts of OOP. Polymorphism is, however, one of the foundations for implementing many design patterns.
- Polymorphism is supported at the language-level; it is not something that you can code into your program.

Comment: Point three is very good, as you rightly mentioned foundations for implementing many design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

There was a Java book written in 1998, still available [at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471227293) which in Chapter 4, called out "Inteface", "Abstract Superclass" and other things as "Fundamental Design Patterns."

This claim was somewhat controversial, as many people would say these are just basic mechanisms rather than "design patterns."

Short answer is: people will give you both answers, though in my experience, most people would say no.